# ADFS Login Error

Tags: java, spring, saml, adfs

When I try to login with adfs with RP I am getting below error. Any one let us know solution.

Encountered error during federation passive request.

Additional Data

Protocol Name:

Relying Party:

Exception details: 
System.NotSupportedException: MSIS0023: SAML signature type 'http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#dsa-sha1' is not supported by the HTTP Redirect binding serializer at this time.
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpRedirectSamlBindingSerializer.CreateFromNameValueCollection(Uri baseUrl, NameValueCollection collection)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Protocols.Saml.HttpRedirectSamlBindingSerializer.ReadMessage(Uri requestUrl, NameValueCollection form)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.HttpSamlMessageFactory.CreateMessage(WrappedHttpListenerRequest httpRequest)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlContextFactory.CreateProtocolContextFromRequest(WrappedHttpListenerRequest request, ProtocolContext& protocolContext)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.Protocols.Saml.SamlProtocolHandler.CreateProtocolContext(WrappedHttpListenerRequest request)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.GetProtocolHandler(WrappedHttpListenerRequest request, ProtocolContext& protocolContext, PassiveProtocolHandler& protocolHandler)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext context)

Answer (score 0):

It means that signature method is not supported by ADFS.

e.g. it supports:

```
xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256"/><ds:Reference URI="#_aab2f88b-026a-4307-8a9a-1eaca6e9468d"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to switch to SHA-256 signatures in your RP.

If this isn't possible for some reason, you can tell ADFS to accept SHA-1 signatures by specifying SHA-1 under the Advanced tab of your relying party's properties in ADFS.

Comment: I have updated the ADFS relaying party to accept SHA-1 format but no luck still same issue.

Comment: I missed the fact you're using a DSA rather than RSA algorithm. Try either http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1 or http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256.

Comment: @Manikandan how do you fixed this issue. I am facing the same issue with RedirectUrl and SHA2